# Profile field visibility

Tags: custom-field, profile

If two users are sharing same profile, how can we make one field visible to one user and hiding it from other user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a permission set, make the field visible within that set, hide the field at the profile level, and assign the permission set to the user that should see the field.

Answer (score 4):

At the profile level we can remove the field level access to both the users and can provide  permissions to access the field to  a particular user  using permission sets